# React Native header clickable with asyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

Essentially, I have a Cloud Icon in the upper right hand corner of my app screen that when I click it I want it to edit an `AsyncStorage` variable in my application. And I am trying to get that variable to change the style of the `<Icon>` class.

To do this, I am trying to make it be a clickable element but I don't know how to transfer this `onClick` to a variable that each screen file sees.

Right now, the icon style ie based on `navigation.state.params.cloud` but that is only established on `ComponentDidMount()` in the each screen file.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

My React-Native app is set up like so:

### index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/config/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MobApp', () => App);
```

### /config/app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, Button, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import { configureFontAwesomePro } from "react-native-fontawesome-pro";
import Icon from "react-native-fontawesome-pro";

configureFontAwesomePro();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

import AuthLoadingScreen from '../screens/AuthLoadingScreen';
import MainScreen from '../screens/main';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/settings';

const cloudLogo = async function() {
  let cloud = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cloud');
    cloud = cloud === 'true';
    cloud = !cloud;

    await AsyncStorage.setItem('cloud', cloud.toString())
    return cloud;
}

var navo = ({ navigation }) => {

  return {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor:"#fff"},
    headerTitle: (<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}><Image style={{ width:25, height: 25, marginTop: 3, marginRight: 5}} source={require('../images/logo.png')}/><Text style={{ color:"#3F61E7", fontSize: 26, fontWeight:"600" }}>MyCompany</Text></View>),
    headerRight: (<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={ async () => {

        let cloud = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cloud');
        cloud = cloud === 'true';
        cloud = !cloud;

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('cloud', cloud.toString())
        console.log((await syncUtil.getLocal()).cloud)

      } } style={{ marginRight:15 }}>
        <Icon name="cloud" type={ typeof navigation.state.params == 'undefined' ? "solid" : (navigation.state.params.cloud ? "solid" : "light") } color="#3F61E7" size={30} />
      </TouchableOpacity>)
  } 
}

const AppStack = StackNavigator({ 
  Home: { screen: MainScreen, navigationOptions: navo },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen, navigationOptions: navo },
});

export default SwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading', 
  }
);
```

Comment: You are basically asking for a global variable, which in React terms means it should go in your main app Component's `state`.

Comment: @ChrisG Anyway you can give me an example of this because it seems like in the navo function, it only ends up checking the global variable when the page loads